# How to Configure ShowcaseView

Tags: android, showcaseview

I am using [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/) from Github.

where i cannot find anything about ConfigOptions and how to use it...

I am writing below code which is commented in samples. and i want to use it. but it shows error on below code because of ShowcaseView file has nothing related to ConfigOptions:

```
   ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions options = new ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions();
    options.shotType = ShowcaseView.TYPE_ONE_SHOT;
    options.showcaseId = 1234;
    views.addView(new ItemViewProperties(R.id.menu_item1, R.string.showcase_menu_item_one_shot_title, R.string.showcase_menu_item_one_shot_message, ShowcaseView.ITEM_SPINNER, SHOWCASE_SPINNER_SCALE, options));
    ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions configOptions = new ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions();
    configOptions.fadeInDuration = 700;
    configOptions.fadeOutDuration = 700;
    configOptions.block = true;
    views.addView(new ItemViewProperties(ItemViewProperties.ID_SPINNER, R.string.showcase_spinner_title, R.string.showcase_spinner_message, ShowcaseView.ITEM_SPINNER, SHOWCASE_SPINNER_SCALE, configOptions));
    views.addView(new ItemViewProperties(ItemViewProperties.ID_OVERFLOW, R.string.showcase_overflow_title, R.string.showcase_overflow_message, ShowcaseView.ITEM_ACTION_OVERFLOW, SHOWCASE_OVERFLOW_ITEM_SCALE));
    views.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the legacy version, please check [that branch's readme](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/tree/legacy) or the [code](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/legacy/library/src/com/espian/showcaseview/ShowcaseView.java#L857) which explains the usage of ConfigOptions.

Or if you can, update to the latest version which is much better supported and documented!